# MKPinAnnotationView not centered

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview

After uploading a custom image for the MKPinAnnotationView, I noticed that the pin was off-centered. The pin is supposed to be on a point on the route's polyline, and in the center of an mkcircle; however, the pin seems to be to the right of the polyline and a little north of the center. I tried experimenting with the centerOffset property, but when I plug values into the property, nothing seems to change. Here is the code,

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

static NSString *viewID = @"MKPinAnnotationView";
MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)
[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:viewID];

if(annotationView ==nil){
    annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:viewID];
}


annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin.png"];
annotationView.enabled = YES;

//doesn't move the pin, still offcentered
annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0,-50);
return annotationView;
 }
```

Just something to add, I also noticed that with the new pin image, nothing pops up when I click on the pin. Before, with the default pin, a bubble of text would appear after clicking on the pin. Since this is the case, I want to include the code for the method that makes and places the pin on the map,

```
-(void) createAndAddAnnotationForCoordinate : (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{

MKPointAnnotation* annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
annotation.title = @"This is a pin!";

[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];


}
```

I also tried changing the pin image to see if that would influence the positioning of the MKPinAnnotationView. Although I was able to center the pin by editing the image, it isn't centered for other polylines. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Picture of the pin]

[image: Picture of the pin relative to the route, polyline, and the circle]

Comment: If you want to use a custom image, create a plain MKAnnotationView (not an MKPinAnnotatioView).  That may fix the centering as well.  To activate callout on tap, do annotationView.canShowCallout = YES.

Comment: Thank you for responding anna. Changing it to MKAnnotationView did solve the callout problem, but the annotation is still off-centered. I tried using the centeroffSet and center properties, but when I mess around with them the annotation doesn't seem to move.

Comment: Note that the centerOffset does not scale with the zoom level of the map.  It's a fixed value so you have to set it so that the point in the image which should stick to the actual coordinate stays that way.  Changing it to MKAnnotationView had nothing to do with the callout (setting canShowCallout did it).

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading correctly, but is there no way I can move the annotation? The annotation is a little to the right of the center of the mkcircle it's placed in if that helps.

Comment: Please edit the question and post the Pin.png and a small screenshot of how the annotation looks on the map relative to the circle.

Comment: Alright I added the pictures you asked!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, an important point is that when using a custom annotation image, it's best to use the plain `MKAnnotationView` class instead of its subclass `MKPinAnnotationView` which is designed to automatically display a standard pin image.

This is because `MKPinAnnotationView` includes some built-in adjustments of the annotation view's frame and centerOffset based on its own pin image.  In some cases, your custom image will even be replaced on the screen with the default pin image.  So even though `MKPinAnnotationView` has an `image` property, the class will not always use it as expected.

Second, set the `centerOffset` such that as the map is zoomed, the part of the image that "points" to the coordinate keeps pointing to the coordinate.  This is because the `centerOffset` is in screen `CGPoint`s and does not scale with the zoom level of the map.  If the `centerOffset` is not set properly, the "point" of the image will start to drift from the target coordinate.

Also note you may not even need to set `centerOffset` since the default will put the center of the image at the coordinate which you may be ok with.

Based on the image you posted, here is the code and resulting appearance ***without setting `centerOffset` (leaving it at the default)***:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    static NSString *viewID = @"MKPinAnnotationView";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:viewID];

    if (annotationView ==nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:viewID];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin.png"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return annotationView;
}
```

[image]

(I added the red center lines to show where the target coordinate is relative to the pin image.)

Here is the code and resulting appearance ***with `centerOffset` set so that the bottom points to the coordinate***:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    static NSString *viewID = @"MKPinAnnotationView";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:viewID];

    if (annotationView ==nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:viewID];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin.png"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0,-15);
    }
    else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return annotationView;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the well-structured answer! I changed my code, but the centerOffset doesn't seem to be doing anything. I'm confused as to why the centerOffset property isn't working. The pin is still in the exact same location.

Comment: I know it's been a few days, but I still haven't been able to find a solution. When I put in any values for the centeroffset property, nothing seems to change. Please help!

Comment: It's weird since calloutOffset is working but not centerOffset

Answer (score 1):

You have to set MKCoordinateRegion to load the map, edit your createAndAddAnnotationForCoordinate method as below

```
-(void) createAndAddAnnotationForCoordinate : (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{

MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 3000, 3000); //Set zooming level
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion]; //add location to map
    [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES]; // create animation zooming

MKPointAnnotation* annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
annotation.title = @"This is a pin!";

[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];


}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The MKCoordinateRegion is being successfully loaded, and the code you added is already in my viewdidLoad method. The pin is still off-centered and the title isn't showing up. However, if I got rid of the overridden viewForAnnotation method, then the pin (with default image) is centered with the title popping up.

Comment: try this code before returning annotationView in viewForAnnotation method,
annotationView.center = CGPointMake(annotationView.bounds.size.width*0.1f, -annotationView.bounds.size.height*0.5f);

Comment: I added the line of code and the pin stay off-centered. Didn't seem that the code moved the pin.

Comment: Then try this, UIImage *pin = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin.png"];
    
    annotationView.center = CGPointMake(pin.size.width*0.1f, -pin.size.height*0.5f);

Comment: Unfortunately, the additional code had no effect on the location of the pin.